# How to iterate over subforms in Twig to display validation errors?

Tags: twig, symfony-2.7

I want to iterate over all fields in my form and display the error  (validation) message by mismatching. I use the following code and it works for all field which are located directly in the form object. For all fields which are located in a subform / merged form does this solution not work.

```
</table>
<div style=" height:180px; overflow:auto;">
<table class="neo-table">
<tbody>
  {% for children in form.children %}
    {% if children.vars.errors is defined %}
       {% for error in children.vars.errors %}
        <tr>
          <td>
           <strong> {{ error.message }}</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

the picture should clarify the problem:

[image: form structure]

I get the error message from all fields which starts with the prefix fu1 but **not** from the fields with the prefix ses f.e the field sesOccupationMother2.

As well i dont get the Information when i use this piece of code:

```
{{form_errors(form.fu1KfPatientid.bSes)}}
```

or something like that:

```
{{form_errors(form)}}
```

i just **get** the Information when i write the FQN from the field like this:

```
{{form_errors(form.fu1KfPatientid.bSes.sesOccupationMother2)}}
```

Whats the reason for this behavour? Does somebody know a trick, how i can use my function and iterate about the errors with the subforms?

Thanks for supporting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now i wrote function, which does not look really nice but it works.

```
{% for children in form.children %}
         {% if children.vars.errors is defined %}
            {% for error in children.vars.errors %}
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong> {{ error.message }}</strong>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %} 
              {% for children in children.children %}
                {% if children.vars.errors is defined %}
                  {% for error in children.vars.errors %}
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                           <strong> {{ error.message }}</strong>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %} 
                     {% for children in children.children %}
                        {% if children.vars.errors is defined %}
                            {% for error in children.vars.errors %}
                             <tr>
                               <td>
                                <strong> {{ error.message }}</strong>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                       {% endfor %}
                       {% endif %} 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```